# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type '....'. NgFor only supports……}

Tags: php, json, angular

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Ashiz",
      "email":"ashizhamal@gmail.com",
      "message":"How are you yankee\r\n",
      "created_at":"2017-05-24 03:16:53",
      "updated_at":"2017-05-24 03:16:53"
   }
]
.map(res => res.json());
```

While i use json data, in above way, than it works fine . That i can use json data but when i use this way as object only than i got error.
 why? what is the differences between square bracket and without square bracket how to work with this?

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "name":"Ashiz",
   "email":"ashizhamal@gmail.com",
   "message":"How are you yankee\r\n",
   "created_at":"2017-05-24 03:16:53",
   "updated_at":"2017-05-24 03:16:53"
}
```

Comment: `[]` is an _array_ or an _iterable_  and `{}` is an _object_ with key-value pairs. `ngFor` needs an iterable..

Comment: If you have just one object, you don't need `*ngFor`, you can just show the properties with e.g `{{objectNameHere?.name}}` notice the safe navigation operator: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Answer (score 1):

When you are not using `[]` the you need to `parse` it with [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) like below.

```
jQuery.parseJSON({  
   "id":1,
   "name":"Ashiz",
   "email":"ashizhamal@gmail.com",
   "message":"How are you yankee\r\n",
   "created_at":"2017-05-24 03:16:53",
   "updated_at":"2017-05-24 03:16:53"
});
```